# Unity/VS debugging only with UnityVS?

Tags: unity, debugging, visual-studio

**Hi,**

this one thing isn't clear to me:
Is it possible, to debug C# of Unity 4.3 with Visual Studio 2013 without any plugin?

If no, what or how else should I debug then?

Comment: Monodevelop is the IDE that ships with Unity, you can debug with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use Visual Studio to debug unity projects if you have unity VS.

From someone who has it, unless you are part of a team and all running unity pro you could probably do fine with unity and it's built in install of monodevelop.

Mono develop still lets you debug your projects just not using visual studio.

The unity VS plugin attaches you to your game code which you can't normally do because it runs within the unity process itself (by design i believe).

Comment: is UnityVs worth it?

Comment: Wardy answered your question nicely, why not accept it first?

Comment: imx ... "worth" depends on your value of being ableto use VS directly with unity, personally i can use either VS or mono develop and be just as happy but then im pretty flexible others have their own "preference" which might result in them considering it being worth more or less. In short: For what it costs ... its not overly expensive in my opinion.

Comment: As painful as MonoDevelop can be, sometimes (or all the time, really), $125.00, plus the subscription fee for updates, for something that, for all intents and purposes, only adds the ability to launch the game from VS, and attach to the Unity process for breakpoint debugging... it's a bit of highway robbery :P  But that's just my opinion.  I'm sure there's plenty of folks out there who would tout the value in the software.  Then again, there are also those who think that Apple computers are inherently superior in every way to any PC, no matter the hardware specs...

Comment: UnityVS doesnt let you run the game from VS just attach to the Unity debugger ... and lately all I seem to do is give them chunks of my code to help them figure their bugs in it ... so yeh it's a bit of a robbery on that basis but I do prefer VS to mono dev, that said maybe v5 will fix my woes with both unity and monodev